# Can't run the jar file nor in Cmd

Tags: java, windows, bluej

I am totally new to programming.I have just started Java and I currently work on BlueJ.My OS is windows.I don't know much about coding.So basically I just made a program.Here's it

```
class  Vedant {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        a = 1;
        if (20>a);
        a = 5;

        {
            System.out.println("Number ="+a);
        }
    }
}
```

I saved this as a Jar file.When I double click on the jar file it doesn't open.I have installed the latest version of Java.If I open with cmd I get an error:Unable to access jar file.
I tried converting the jar file to exe using Launch4J but the exe file doesn't open.Any Help

And yea I am a Extreme Beginner in Java so I don't understand much of it.

Comment: "*I  saved this as a Jar file.*" - How did you do that? I assume you used the `jar` command? If so, please include the exact command used to generate the jar. "*When I double click on the jar file it doesn't open.*" - You need to specify which class to start (that's what the `META-INF ` folder and the `manifest.mf` file within the jar archive are for). If you do not have specified it, try running `java -cp /path/to/your.jar YourClassContainingTheMain`

Comment: @Turing85 I think you meant `-cp` rather than `-jar`.

Comment: @VGR is it `-cp` in this case? I was under the impression it should be possible with `jar` as well... ^^ will edit my last comment.

Comment: @Vedant also you need to check your PATH variable, and add java to PATH if it isn't there

Comment: I took the liberty and reformated your code. A few remarks: `int a; a = 1;` can be simplified to `int a = 1;` - `if (20>a);` the trailing semicolon win basically "disable" the `if` (the semicolon says "do nothing if you enter the `if`). You open a block code afterwards. I think you wanted to open the block AFTER the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to open the file using a terminal.

As you are a windows user, you can use **command prompt**.

1. Open Command Prompt by pressing `Win+R`, type `cmd` and press `Enter`.
2. Use this command for running your file in command prompt.

   java -jar (Full path to jar file)

If you get an error showing that java cannot be found, then make sure that you have java installed in your PC.

If installed, set your Java Path in your System Environment Variables.

Step by step process on how to set your Java path is given [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

After setting your java path, you will be able to run your jar file using the command.

### Points to keep in mind:

- While creating Jar file from BlueJ select main class as "Vedant" from the drop down list. By default, none(cannot be executed) is selected.

[image: See the image]

After that it can successfully be executed: 
(Replace `C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar` with the link to your jar file)

```
C:\Users\Midhun>java -jar C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar
Number =5
```

If you don't select the main class while creating the jar file, you will get the following error.

```
C:\Users\Midhun>java -jar C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

You can overcome this error by either recreating jar with main class or executing the following command

```
C:\Users\Midhun>java -cp C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar Vedant
Number =5
```

`C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar` is the full path to jar file and `Vedant` is the name of main class that you want to run from the jar file.

**If you give the wrong link to the jar file you will get the following error as mentioned in your question.**

```
C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop>java -jar C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedan.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile vedan.jar
```

Comment: It gives me Could not find or load main class folder\New Folder..Anyways thanks for replying

Comment: @Vedant See my edited answer. I reproduced the same error that you got. Recreate the jar file with the **main class** selected. If you leave it empty you will get `Error: Could not find or load main class `

Comment: :C .. Unable to access jar file

Comment: Did you recreate the jar file? And where did u save the file and how exactly you tried to execute it. 

Try using `java -jar (Full path to jar file)`
Example: `java -jar C:\Users\Vedant\Documents\vedant.jar`

The error ` Unable to access jar file` will be obtained when the location of jar file is given wrong.

Comment: **Additional Info:**  You can also run the jar without selecting the main class by `C:\Users\Midhun>java -cp C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar Vedant` where `C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar` is the Link to the JAR File and `Vedant` is the name of main class in your jar file which you would like to run.

Comment: Thank you so much..It worked.But it doesn't ask me for an input.It just shows me an answer as Number=5..I just made a new directory.And is there any way I can convert it to .exe file?I tried Launch4j but the .exe file doesn't launch

Comment: For taking input you will have to use [Scanner](https://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class).

Comment: There is no use of converting it into an exe file. If you want a shortcut which will open it without typing in command prompt, then `right click on your desktop`, `click create shortcut`. In the path, type in `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k java -jar C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\vedant.jar` (change the path) and you can run the jar from that shortcut

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .cmd file that includes the following text:
java -jar path_for_your_jar_file

save it and just click on that file. It will launch your program (this is the procedure instead of entering each time to the command prompt).

Comment: The "procedure" would be to [define the application's entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).